# Properties of converging functions

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,\mathcal{B}(X),\mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $f_n\colon X\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ functions, such that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\mu\left(\left\{x\in X\colon \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x,y)=f(y)\right\}\right)=\mu(X),$$
where $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the limit function. Then
$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{y\in \mathbb{R}}\left\{x\in X\colon \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x,y)=f(y)\right\}\right)=\mu(X).$$

What properties must $f_n$ have in order for the second equation to hold. I know that we can choose a dense subset $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and using countable additivity, we get
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{Q}}\left\{x\in X\colon \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x,y)\neq f(y) \right\}\right)=\sum_{y\in\mathbb{Q}}\mu\left(\left\{x\in X\colon \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x,y)\neq f(y) \right\}\right)=0,$$
which means that the second equation holds for
\begin{equation}\mu\left(\bigcap_{y\in \mathbb{Q}}\left\{x\in X\colon \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x,y)=f(y)\right\}\right)=\mu(X).\end{equation}
What should I do with $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?